# Error connecting to online database android

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to establish a connection between my android app and an online host, however, I am getting the following error in the cpanel's `error_log`:

```
[27-Feb-2017 14:19:14 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'whiteweb_root'@'209.99.16.16' (using password: YES) in /home/whiteweb/public_html/conn.php on line 6
```

Here is `conn.php`:

```
<?php
$host = "209.99.16.16";
$mysql_username = "whiteweb_root";
$mysql_pwd = "123456";
$db_name = "whiteweb_deliverus";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $mysql_username, $mysql_pwd, $db_name);
?>
```

The error seems to occur as I try to establish a connection using `mysqli_connect` but I believe I have written it properly. All the arguments for `mysqli_connect` are correct and I have assigned the user to the database in the cpanel and given the user all privileges. Additionally, the code in my android application is correct and it worked perfectly using `wampserver`.

I have tried looking for a solution online to no avail. Any help on how to fix the problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: First of all I can't get the `android` tag!!

After that, make sure your user has the read permission for this database.

Comment: the `android` tag is because it is android related. I can't see read among the privileges

Comment: Most probably your setting on cPanel is wrong. Have you given remote access to that user? if not change it, then tell me and I will answer the question and then you can mark it.

Comment: thanks for that. I added the host to remote mysql and the problem has been fixed. thanks a lot

Comment: Hi George can you vote up my answer and mark it the correct please. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your setting on cPanel is wrong. Have you given remote access to that user? If not do so and all will be good. :)

Comment: if both PHP and mysql are on the same server then, use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` instead of enabling remote connection on mysql. --security wise talking--

Comment: it is an android code triggered from a mobile phone as far as I can establish, so it needs to have remote access, unless android code triggers a local PHP code then yes that will be a wise thing to do.

Comment: it's PHP code, as you can see in the question, and android app is calling this PHP page. so yes. although we are not sure if PHP code is hosted on same machine with Mysql, OP did not answer that question.

Comment: yes @DanielPurPur is right.  It is an android code from a mobile phone so it does need remote access

Answer (score 0):

it looks that your configuration for mysql access is restricted to `localhost` aka `127.0.0.1`

this line

```
$host = "209.99.16.16";
```

tries to connect to the database but it will behave (at least for Mysql server) as if it was a remote connection.
if your code (php) and db server are located on the same machine, then use this host instead

```
$host = "127.0.0.1"; // or localhost
```

Comment: the server is remote and i only had to add remote access to it but thanks for your answer